# Hive SQL: Running a query so that if the 1st subquery returns 0 results, it will then return the results of a 2nd subquery

Tags: sql, hive, subquery

I'm trying to write a Hive SQL query that will then run a 2nd query if the results of the first query are empty / null. For instance, my 1st query might look like this:

```
SELECT
calendar_date
, store_id
, total_inventory
FROM sales_table
WHERE calendar_date= datesub(current_date,1)
```

If that query returns 0 results, then I want it to run a 2nd query that modifies the where condition for date:

```
SELECT
calendar_date
, store_id
, total_inventory
FROM sales_table
WHERE calendar_date= datesub(current_date,2)
```

Google Bard recommended using a 'with clause', but I could never get it to work properly. For instance:

```
WITH inv_1 as (
    SELECT
    calendar_date
    , store_id
    , total_inventory
    FROM sales_table
    WHERE calendar_date= datesub(current_date,1)
), 
inv_2 as (
    SELECT
    calendar_date
    , store_id
    , total_inventory
    FROM sales_table
    WHERE calendar_date= datesub(current_date,2)
)
SELECT *
FROM inv_1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM inv2
WHERE inv1 IS NULL
```

That query works until the final where clause. Is there a way to make it work or an alternative that works better?

Most of the other recommendations I see involve using a coalesce() statement, but I think that only works for 1 column, not an entire subquery.